# Loop linear regrssion model

Tags: r, loops, linear-regression

I have a data like this where Amount is the dependent variable and  len,age, quantity and pos are explanotry variables. I trying to Make a regression of Amount On age, quantity and pos Using stepwise.

```
    ID Sym Month Amount len Age quantity  Pos
    11  10   1    500    5   17   0       12
    22  10   1    300    6   11   0       11 
    33  10   1    200    2   10   0       10
    44  10   1    100    2   11   0       11
    55  10   1    150    4   15   0       12
    66  10   1    250    4   16   0       14
    11  20   1    500    5   17   0       12
    22  20   1    300    6   11   0       11 
    33  20   1    200    2   10   0       10
    44  20   1    100    2   11   0       11
    55  20   1    150    4   15   0       12
    66  20   1    250    4   16   0       14
    77  20   1    700    4   17   0       11
    88  20   1    100    2   16   0       12
    11  30   1    500    5   17   0       12
    22  30   1    300    6   11   0       11 
    33  30   1    200    2   10   0       10
    44  30   1    100    2   11   0       11
    55  30   1    150    4   15   0       12
    66  30   1    250    4   16   0       14
    11  40   1    500    5   17   2000    12
    22  40   1    300    6   11   1000    11 
    33  40   1    200    2   10   1000    10
    44  40   1    100    2   11   1000    11
    55  40   1    150    4   15   1000    12
    66  40   1    250    4   16   1000    14
```

And the Output of the results I want after running all regression should be a dataframe that's look like this (That should help me detect outliers):

```
Id Month Sym Amount len Age Quantity Pos R^2 CookDistanse  Residuals UpperLimit LowerLimit
11   1    10  500    5   17   null    12  0.7   1.5         -350      -500       1000 
22   1    10  300    6   11   null    11  0.8   1.7         -400      -500       1000
```

That's the code that I am trying to run on Sym = 10, Sym= 20, Sym = 30, Sym = 40.
I have something like 400 Sym values to run a regression analysis on them.

```
fit[i]  <-  step(lm (Sym[i]$Sum ~ len + Age + Quantity,
                    na.action=na.omit), direction="backward")
R_Sq <- summary(fit[i])$r.squared
Res[i] <- resid(fit[i])
D[i] <- cooks.distance(fit[i]) 
Q[i] <- quantile(resid(fit[i), c(.25, .50,  .75, .99))
L[i]<-  Q[1][i] - 2.2* (Q[3][i]-Q[1][i])
U[i] <- Q[3][i] + 2.2*(Q[3][i]-Q[1][i])
```

"i" means the results for the regression of sym = i (10,20..). 
Any way to do this on loop for every Sym value? 
Any help will be highly appreciate.

Comment: You are aware of the fundamental problems with stepwise regression?

Comment: can you explain? although my problem is technical with r script.

Comment: http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/20856/11849

Comment: And for your programming problem: You need a split-apply-combine-like function. There are many alternatives, but I prefer package data.table.

Comment: Could you give me Any example?

Comment: You want to fit a single model for each single value of the dependent variable Sym? One at a time? Really?

Comment: Yes, what is the problem? Sym is a value close to diffrent countries.